# Как в android реализовать такую ситуацию?

Tags: android

Есть activity - по нажатию на кнопку переходим 2-ое activity, В 2-ом activity запускается таймер. Следующее надо убить процесс приложения, и обратно по клику по приложению должно открыться 2-ое activity все еще работающим таймером? в какую сторону копать? может подкините какой нибудь пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копать следует в сторону `Intent`, `startActivity`, `finishAffinity`, возможно, `Service`.